# MongoDb Text Search On Different fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection looks this:

```
{ _id: 1, author: "Jack London", bookName: "The Sea-Wolf" }
{ _id: 2, author: "Alex Kershaw", bookName: "Jack London" }
```

I want to be able to search by **author** or by **bookName** only, but MongoDB allows you to create only 1 text index. Thanks for help.

For Example:
I wanna search for author only :

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"Jack London"}})//search in 'author' field
```

Or by bookName only :

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"Jack London"}})//search in 'bookName' field
```

If I have compound index `{author: "text", bookName: "text"}` it will return me both entries, which is not what I want.